# Python: Simple Question regarding counting characters on a list of strings

Tags: python, string

this is a simple questions but I just cant get the following code to work in a loop. Outside the loop it works. Im sorry to bother with something so simple but Im learning Python:

**Code in loop:**

```
c=[]
for i in b:
  s=len(b[i])
  c.append(s)
c
```

I have also tried with "range(3)" instead of b for the loop header.
The error I get is: "TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()"

When I do the following (manually) it works great but I cant seem to use it on a loop:

```
s=len(b[1])
s

c=[]

ii=0
pa=len(b[ii])

c.append(pa)
```

I hope you can help me and once again Im sorry for the dumb question

Comment: May I kindly suggest you do the full python tutorial ? [this is explained here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements)

Answer (score 1):

Bro try enumerate, you are taking the variable i as the index of the list b. It contains the current value of b in the loop. 
you can either use enumerate or take a look at this code

```
c=[]
for i in b:
  s=len(i)
  c.append(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

different from other languages ,i does not take index ,it takes value. you need to write following code

`s=len(i)`

Ex:

 `b=[5,3,112] 
 for i in b:
     print(i)`
output will  be  5,3,112